# Which size ads should I place in Garland theme pages?

Tags: drupal, drupal-6

I'm using garland theme for my [site](http://www.indiacustomercare.com). I'm ready to place ad's in the top and bottom.
But this theme isn't fixed layout.  I mean when I move browser to 800x600 monitor the content region is resized to smaller one.

So I was thinking to place banner ad of 728 width, but when the window is small then this ad will cut off. I've another option of trying with 468 width ad banner.


My question is how should I choose an ad banner and also make sure that it does not get cutoff when window is resized to smaller dimension?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case you have to choose based on the lowest resolution you want to support.

468x60 banners are pretty standard and should be small enough to fit on scaled down browsers or smaller resolution screens.

Answer (score 2):

well, if you want the long answer... find out the resolution the user is using and set your banner acordingly.

steps:

give an ID to your banner image (or div).

put this script in the head of your page.tpl.php or create a file.js and include it in your template.info.

```
<SCRIPT language="JavaScript">
<!--
if (screen.width>=1024)
{
  document.getElementById("idElement").setAttribute("width", "1000px");
}
else if (screen.width>=800)
{
  document.getElementById("idElement").setAttribute("width", "780px");
} 
else
{
  document.getElementById("idElement").setAttribute("width", "480px");
}
//-->
</SCRIPT>
```

note: change "idElement" with the id of your banner.

EDIT:

So you're using something like google ads right? Then you can use the same logic above, with a few tweaks. For instance...

You can put 3 banner ads inside `<div>` tags. Let's say you have a banner with 1000 width, 800 width and 300 width.

```
<div id="banner-1000" style="display: none;">[code for bannerx1000]</div>
<div id="banner-800" style="display: none;">[code for banner 800]</div>
<div id="banner-300" style="display: none;">[code for banner 300]</div>
```

now in the js script I gave you above change

```
document.getElementById("idElement").setAttribute("width", "1000px");
```

with

```
document.getElementById("idElement").setAttribute("style", "display: block;");
```

So basically you place all banners in your page but they are hidden. When the jscript browser resolution, it unhides the div showing the appropriate banner.

You can also use `<iframe>` tags and place your banner code in other file. Same logic.

Or you can use PHP ans JS to acomplish this... [Detect screen resolution using PHP](http://www.webmasterworld.com/forum88/4700.htm) but I think is kind of overshot.

Comment: Well banner ad is for specific size( among many other sizes), so I can place this width in css only so dynamic resizing will not be needed.